# Importing and Connecting to Derby Database at Netbeans IDE error

Tags: java, mysql, database, netbeans, jdbc

I am total novice in this topic. In general, my friend created derby database in netbeans. All databases were stored in directory:

```
 home/.netbeans-derby
```

He ziped the folder with database he created, and sent to me. I entered unziped database folder to my directory (screen with it:https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/108321090/DATABASE_FOLDERS.png) :

```
C:\Users\Fisher\.netbeans-derby
```

Netbeans finds this database and shows it in the tree under Java DB. When use "Connect" on this database I get error (screen with it: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/108321090/DB_ERROR.png):

Unable to connect. Cannot estabilish a connection to jdbc:derby//localhost:1527/mydatabase using org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver (DERBY SQL error: SQLCODE -1, SQLSTATE: XJ040, SQLERRMC: Starting database 'mydatabase' failed. Details are containing exception.::SQLSTATE: XSAI2. Demanded conglomeration (16) doesnt exist.).

And also I can provide you with log txt from my folder which is rly long so: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/108321090/derby.log

Please tell me is there any easy way to connect to that database or is there any EASY way to export base if it was done in wrong way? Please help me.

Comment: post your code show that we can check what might be the error

Comment: I'm not using any code. I just want to import DB to NetBeans and click "connect" in the project tree (in Java DB section) on it - so it works and I can see it's structure (open it). I want it to work the same way as Sample  is.